# Newbie question: how to add block, add transaction and search transaction in blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, blockchain

I am new to this. I wanted to know, how i can add block, add transaction and search for transaction in blockchain?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are asking for Ethereum Blockchain.

> I wanted to know, how i can add block

Adding a block in Ethereum requires mining. You can find more about mining [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining).

> add transaction

Transaction can be added using `eth.sendTransaction` more details about it can be found at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contracts-and-Transactions

> search for transaction in blockchain

Transaction details can be found from the transaction hash that we get when we send a transaction. Use `eth.getTransaction(txHash)`, to get the details of the transaction.